# How to resolve consistent segmentation faults with ruby 1.9.3-p125 on MacOS Lion in libsystem_kernel.dylib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, segmentation-fault, osx-lion

Rails 3.1.3 and/or 3.2.2. I am unable to determine the cause, would be grateful for any help. I get these intermittently but inconsistently when using WEBrick 1.3.1, but not if I run Unicorn. I am suspicious that it might be related somehow to the asset pipeline.

Ruby 1.9.3-p125 compiled with `CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 ./configure --prefix=$HOME/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125 -C --enable-shared`

Any tips of where to begin would be much appreciated.

Contents from Crash Reporter log:

```
Process:         ruby [84846]
Path:            /Users/USER/*/ruby
Identifier:      ruby
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  zsh [579]

Date/Time:       2012-03-07 18:57:47.019 -0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.3 (11D50b)
Report Version:  9

Crashed Thread:  3

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000108535f38

VM Regions Near 0x108535f38:
    MALLOC_LARGE (reserved 0000000108468000-0000000108528000 [  768K] rw-/rwx SM=NUL  reserved VM address space (unallocated)
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010853e000-000000010855c000 [  120K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Users/USER/*/ffi_c.bundle

Application Specific Information:
objc[84846]: garbage collection is OFF
abort() called

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8ebebbca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff925ba274 _pthread_cond_wait + 840
2   ruby                            0x00000001078e9e4b gvl_acquire + 107
3   ruby                            0x00000001078ee298 rb_thread_fd_select + 680
4   ruby                            0x00000001077c769f select_call + 1071
5   ruby                            0x000000010779e1af rb_ensure + 127
6   ruby                            0x00000001077bf5ae rb_f_select + 158
7   ruby                            0x00000001078e0717 vm_call_method + 999
8   ruby                            0x00000001078ce813 vm_exec_core + 18819
9   ruby                            0x00000001078d34d3 vm_exec + 1459
10  ruby                            0x00000001078e3280 rb_yield + 640
11  ruby                            0x00000001077eebd1 rb_obj_tap + 17
12  ruby                            0x00000001078e0717 vm_call_method + 999
13  ruby                            0x00000001078ce813 vm_exec_core + 18819
14  ruby                            0x00000001078d34d3 vm_exec + 1459
15  ruby                            0x00000001078d3960 rb_iseq_eval + 368
16  ruby                            0x00000001077a1feb rb_load_internal + 331
17  ruby                            0x00000001077a3d09 rb_require_safe + 1145
18  ruby                            0x00000001078e0717 vm_call_method + 999
19  ruby                            0x00000001078ce813 vm_exec_core + 18819
20  ruby                            0x00000001078d34d3 vm_exec + 1459
21  ruby                            0x00000001078d37cc rb_iseq_eval_main + 508
22  ruby                            0x000000010779e832 ruby_exec_internal + 178
23  ruby                            0x00000001077a132c ruby_run_node + 60
24  ruby                            0x000000010775f7bf main + 79
25  ruby                            0x000000010775f764 start + 52

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8ebebdf2 __select + 10
1   ruby                            0x00000001078eabfb thread_timer + 299
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff925b68bf _pthread_start + 335
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff925b9b75 thread_start + 13

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8ebebbca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff925ba274 _pthread_cond_wait + 840
2   ruby                            0x00000001078ea7de native_sleep + 270
3   ruby                            0x00000001078eb39a sleep_timeval + 170
4   ruby                            0x000000010781f350 rb_f_sleep + 80
5   ruby                            0x00000001078e0717 vm_call_method + 999
6   ruby                            0x00000001078ce813 vm_exec_core + 18819
7   ruby                            0x00000001078d34d3 vm_exec + 1459
8   ruby                            0x00000001078d483d rb_vm_invoke_proc + 877
9   ruby                            0x00000001078ec649 thread_start_func_2 + 1625
10  ruby                            0x00000001078ec776 thread_start_func_1 + 150
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff925b68bf _pthread_start + 335
12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff925b9b75 thread_start + 13

Thread 3 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8ebebce2 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff925b87d2 pthread_kill + 95
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff925a9a7a abort + 143
3   ruby                            0x0000000107799c04 rb_bug + 212
4   ruby                            0x000000010786204f sigsegv + 127
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff9260acfa _sigtramp + 26
6   ruby                            0x00000001077b6298 gc_marks + 296
7   ruby                            0x00000001077b775e rb_newobj + 494
8   ruby                            0x00000001077b7f19 rb_node_newnode + 41
9   ruby                            0x00000001078c7c7d rb_backref_get + 141
10  ruby                            0x0000000107839eef rb_reg_search + 207
11  ruby                            0x000000010783a619 rb_reg_match_m + 57
12  ruby                            0x00000001078e0717 vm_call_method + 999
13  ruby                            0x00000001078ce813 vm_exec_core + 18819
14  ruby                            0x00000001078d34d3 vm_exec + 1459
15  ruby                            0x00000001078e3280 rb_yield + 640
16  ruby                            0x0000000107795b18 find_all_i + 56
17  ruby                            0x00000001078e3533 rb_yield + 1331
18  ruby                            0x00000001077650ee rb_ary_each + 78
19  ruby                            0x00000001078d4c82 vm_call0 + 610
20  ruby                            0x00000001078d795e iterate_method + 366
21  ruby                            0x00000001078c65ca rb_iterate + 234
22  ruby                            0x00000001078c678d rb_block_call + 45
23  ruby                            0x0000000107792a63 enum_find_all + 115
24  ruby                            0x00000001078e0717 vm_call_method + 999
25  ruby                            0x00000001078ce813 vm_exec_core + 18819
26  ruby                            0x00000001078d34d3 vm_exec + 1459
27  ruby                            0x00000001078d483d rb_vm_invoke_proc + 877
28  ruby                            0x00000001078ec649 thread_start_func_2 + 1625
29  ruby                            0x00000001078ec776 thread_start_func_1 + 150
30  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff925b68bf _pthread_start + 335
31  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff925b9b75 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8ebebbca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff925ba274 _pthread_cond_wait + 840
2   ruby                            0x00000001078e9e4b gvl_acquire + 107
3   ruby                            0x00000001078ede75 rb_thread_blocking_region + 165
4   socket.bundle                   0x0000000107eb4868 rsock_ipaddr + 216
5   socket.bundle                   0x0000000107ead29d ip_addr + 173
6   ruby                            0x00000001078e0717 vm_call_method + 999
7   ruby                            0x00000001078ce813 vm_exec_core + 18819
8   ruby                            0x00000001078d34d3 vm_exec + 1459
9   ruby                            0x00000001078d483d rb_vm_invoke_proc + 877
10  ruby                            0x00000001078ec649 thread_start_func_2 + 1625
11  ruby                            0x00000001078ec776 thread_start_func_1 + 150
12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff925b68bf _pthread_start + 335
13  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff925b9b75 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8ebebbca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff925ba274 _pthread_cond_wait + 840
2   ruby                            0x00000001078e9e4b gvl_acquire + 107
3   ruby                            0x00000001078ede75 rb_thread_blocking_region + 165
4   socket.bundle                   0x0000000107eb4868 rsock_ipaddr + 216
5   socket.bundle                   0x0000000107ead29d ip_addr + 173
6   ruby                            0x00000001078e0717 vm_call_method + 999
7   ruby                            0x00000001078ce813 vm_exec_core + 18819
8   ruby                            0x00000001078d34d3 vm_exec + 1459
9   ruby                            0x00000001078d483d rb_vm_invoke_proc + 877
10  ruby                            0x00000001078ec649 thread_start_func_2 + 1625
11  ruby                            0x00000001078ec776 thread_start_func_1 + 150
12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff925b68bf _pthread_start + 335
13  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff925b9b75 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8ebebbca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff925ba274 _pthread_cond_wait + 840
2   ruby                            0x00000001078e9e4b gvl_acquire + 107
3   ruby                            0x00000001078ede75 rb_thread_blocking_region + 165
4   socket.bundle                   0x0000000107eb4984 rsock_ipaddr + 500
5   socket.bundle                   0x0000000107ead3fd ip_peeraddr + 173
6   ruby                            0x00000001078e0717 vm_call_method + 999
7   ruby                            0x00000001078ce813 vm_exec_core + 18819
8   ruby                            0x00000001078d34d3 vm_exec + 1459
9   ruby                            0x00000001078d483d rb_vm_invoke_proc + 877
10  ruby                            0x00000001078ec649 thread_start_func_2 + 1625
11  ruby                            0x00000001078ec776 thread_start_func_1 + 150
12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff925b68bf _pthread_start + 335
13  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff925b9b75 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8ebebbca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff925ba274 _pthread_cond_wait + 840
2   ruby                            0x00000001078e9e4b gvl_acquire + 107
3   ruby                            0x00000001078ede75 rb_thread_blocking_region + 165
4   socket.bundle                   0x0000000107eb4984 rsock_ipaddr + 500
5   socket.bundle                   0x0000000107ead3fd ip_peeraddr + 173
6   ruby                            0x00000001078e0717 vm_call_method + 999
7   ruby                            0x00000001078ce813 vm_exec_core + 18819
8   ruby                            0x00000001078d34d3 vm_exec + 1459
9   ruby                            0x00000001078d483d rb_vm_invoke_proc + 877
10  ruby                            0x00000001078ec649 thread_start_func_2 + 1625
11  ruby                            0x00000001078ec776 thread_start_func_1 + 150
12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff925b68bf _pthread_start + 335
13  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff925b9b75 thread_start + 13

Thread 3 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000006  rcx: 0x000000010966c938  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x000000000000345f  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x000000010966c960  rsp: 0x000000010966c938
   r8: 0x00007fff7862cfb8   r9: 0x000000010966c4c8  r10: 0x00007fff8ebebd0a  r11: 0xffffff80002d8220
  r12: 0x00007fab7c9a9840  r13: 0x00007fab7e810eb0  r14: 0x0000000109771000  r15: 0xcccccccccccccccd
  rip: 0x00007fff8ebebce2  rfl: 0x0000000000000246  cr2: 0xffffff8112bcad20
Logical CPU: 0

Binary Images:
       0x10775e000 -        0x10797fff7 +ruby (??? - ???) <F67A69E6-8F3F-36C0-8128-2E515BC6FB28> /Users/USER/*/ruby
       0x107adf000 -        0x107ae0fff +encdb.bundle (??? - ???) <CC2FD16A-6FA9-33CC-98D2-D63F358E6B5E> /Users/USER/*/encdb.bundle
       0x107ae3000 -        0x107ae4ff7 +transdb.bundle (??? - ???) <E50EA0BA-488D-3ED7-A02B-3495F159297E> /Users/USER/*/transdb.bundle
       0x107ae7000 -        0x107aeeff7 +pathname.bundle (??? - ???) <3F841DFF-8D3F-3B2E-BC2D-C624CB0A6463> /Users/USER/*/pathname.bundle
       0x107af5000 -        0x107af6ff7 +etc.bundle (??? - ???) <B7CD4C2F-3847-3231-ABA0-08C48D7E4F01> /Users/USER/*/etc.bundle
       0x107afb000 -        0x107afbfff +sha1.bundle (??? - ???) <81255934-7D84-34D7-B1C1-346CB019E1D3> /Users/USER/*/sha1.bundle
       0x107d00000 -        0x107d03fff +psych.bundle (??? - ???) <33395735-DCE9-3D85-AA2E-8EC52086C773> /Users/USER/*/psych.bundle
       0x107d09000 -        0x107d26fff +libyaml-0.2.dylib (3.2.0 - compatibility 3.0.0) <2E7F9734-BB6E-3EBC-A116-EA21CEA1638F> /Users/USER/*/libyaml-0.2.dylib
       0x107d2e000 -        0x107d33fff +stringio.bundle (??? - ???) <BB58B88B-CD6C-382C-9AC5-C0462E9EE224> /Users/USER/*/stringio.bundle
       0x107d38000 -        0x107d3bfff +strscan.bundle (??? - ???) <E9AB0034-C453-3069-9E93-ADD5A10DE433> /Users/USER/*/strscan.bundle
       0x107d40000 -        0x107d75fef +date_core.bundle (??? - ???) <C7732A69-58E7-3498-AD53-6F6A4DAA6C4F> /Users/USER/*/date_core.bundle
       0x107d8f000 -        0x107d91ff7 +digest.bundle (??? - ???) <A5910EC9-399F-34BB-8CA0-91E16E88CFAF> /Users/USER/*/digest.bundle
       0x107d95000 -        0x107d95fff +iso_8859_1.bundle (??? - ???) <6D7A924B-19B5-3500-BA08-038D37BEED8F> /Users/USER/*/iso_8859_1.bundle
       0x107d98000 -        0x107da3ff7 +zlib.bundle (??? - ???) <8EA2317A-27C6-3BC6-848E-CFAF9194E8DA> /Users/USER/*/zlib.bundle
       0x107dda000 -        0x107e15fff +openssl.bundle (??? - ???) <0BE4DBFA-0F3F-3EF2-96C3-066C9DF22627> /Users/USER/*/openssl.bundle
       0x107e44000 -        0x107e44ff7 +fcntl.bundle (??? - ???) <72BF0D6E-DED0-32CC-A3B2-7F0706468A41> /Users/USER/*/fcntl.bundle
       0x107e47000 -        0x107e57fff +bigdecimal.bundle (??? - ???) <F7A9B0B1-F3EE-3C0E-BE05-58303716A76C> /Users/USER/*/bigdecimal.bundle
       0x107e5e000 -        0x107e70fe7 +single_byte.bundle (??? - ???) <B06784E3-0E2A-3F5E-8A30-8AF02C5814DE> /Users/USER/*/single_byte.bundle
       0x107e79000 -        0x107e79fef +escape.bundle (??? - ???) <EF012DE8-401A-3A11-BF42-48BB3B2101E3> /Users/USER/*/escape.bundle
       0x107e7c000 -        0x107e80fef +parser.bundle (??? - ???) <E8CA6BEA-6A6A-330E-B421-977C601E76FB> /Users/USER/*/parser.bundle
       0x107e85000 -        0x107e85fff +utf_16be.bundle (??? - ???) <71664F37-8EFA-3537-8849-44787A17EEDE> /Users/USER/*/utf_16be.bundle
       0x107e88000 -        0x107e88fff +utf_16le.bundle (??? - ???) <81C2E44D-327F-3173-8DB5-A4F447D1B5C1> /Users/USER/*/utf_16le.bundle
       0x107e8b000 -        0x107e8bfff +utf_32be.bundle (??? - ???) <593D338B-F729-3C52-BC41-D726C55EC16C> /Users/USER/*/utf_32be.bundle
       0x107e8e000 -        0x107e8efff +utf_32le.bundle (??? - ???) <79810620-3BD5-3978-AC60-CD9A2AA25AC9> /Users/USER/*/utf_32le.bundle
       0x107e91000 -        0x107e97fe7 +generator.bundle (??? - ???) <FA6AB0AF-088F-394D-8FB6-E760B7B95188> /Users/USER/*/generator.bundle
       0x107e9e000 -        0x107ebeff7 +socket.bundle (??? - ???) <A09A498B-4585-3D0A-B673-0F76A628DA31> /Users/USER/*/socket.bundle
       0x107ece000 -        0x107ed4fff +kgio_ext.bundle (??? - ???) <92BA2CFA-0F9A-3FDB-86DC-331D37E802A2> /Users/USER/*/kgio_ext.bundle
       0x107edb000 -        0x107ee4ff7 +unicorn_http.bundle (??? - ???) <6F47A521-1C62-382F-9508-3C036241AE17> /Users/USER/*/unicorn_http.bundle
       0x107ee9000 -        0x107eeafff +raindrops_ext.bundle (??? - ???) <3E00DB91-6D12-3FDC-967B-F15576C20B93> /Users/USER/*/raindrops_ext.bundle
       0x107eed000 -        0x107eedff7 +md5.bundle (??? - ???) <85C04DCD-6155-3789-AC13-FE29483C0019> /Users/USER/*/md5.bundle
       0x107ef0000 -        0x107ef2fff +cparse.bundle (??? - ???) <4AA12B44-A1EE-3D47-A44A-1B3D33C397E5> /Users/USER/*/cparse.bundle
       0x108036000 -        0x108048fff +nokogiri.bundle (??? - ???) <D5681380-EF69-32FD-B43B-066FC820ACA9> /Users/USER/*/nokogiri.bundle
       0x10823c000 -        0x108241fff +sqlite3_native.bundle (??? - ???) <5CFDB871-B73B-3FF4-AB79-D0BAAE9F6326> /Users/USER/*/sqlite3_native.bundle
       0x10853e000 -        0x10855bfff +ffi_c.bundle (??? - ???) <2A06D7CD-D796-3FF0-AA88-B8F492553823> /Users/USER/*/ffi_c.bundle
    0x7fff6735e000 -     0x7fff67392baf  dyld (195.6 - ???) <0CD1B35B-A28F-32DA-B72E-452EAD609613> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff86e38000 -     0x7fff86e39ff7  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (??? - ???) <5087ADAD-D34D-3844-9D04-AFF93CED3D92> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff8801d000 -     0x7fff8801efff  libdnsinfo.dylib (395.7.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <37FEFE78-BCB5-37EC-8E99-747469BCA4C7> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
    0x7fff88575000 -     0x7fff88587ff7  libz.1.dylib (1.2.5 - compatibility 1.0.0) <30CBEF15-4978-3DED-8629-7109880A19D4> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff8912f000 -     0x7fff89137fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (??? - ???) <998E3778-7B43-301C-9053-12045AB8544D> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fff89138000 -     0x7fff89145fff  libexslt.0.dylib (9.13.0 - compatibility 9.0.0) <0AF8D6E4-BDDC-39F9-84E9-02C3C1E9F82A> /usr/lib/libexslt.0.dylib
    0x7fff891ac000 -     0x7fff89290e5f  libobjc.A.dylib (228.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <871E688B-CF57-3BC7-80D6-F6476DFF109B> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff8a22e000 -     0x7fff8a2a1fff  libstdc++.6.dylib (52.0.0 - compatibility 7.0.0) <6BDD43E4-A4B1-379E-9ED5-8C713653DFF2> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
    0x7fff8a557000 -     0x7fff8a584fe7  libSystem.B.dylib (159.1.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <7BEBB139-50BB-3112-947A-F4AA168F991C> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff8a6e9000 -     0x7fff8a6efff7  libunwind.dylib (30.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <1E9C6C8C-CBE8-3F4B-A5B5-E03E3AB53231> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff8b3d9000 -     0x7fff8b3daff7  libsystem_blocks.dylib (53.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <8BCA214A-8992-34B2-A8B9-B74DEACA1869> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x7fff8c4df000 -     0x7fff8c5ebfff  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (44.0.0 - compatibility 0.9.8) <3A8E1F89-5E26-3C8B-B538-81F5D61DBF8A> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
    0x7fff8c5ec000 -     0x7fff8c62eff7  libcommonCrypto.dylib (55010.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <BB770C22-8C57-365A-8716-4A3C36AE7BFB> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fff8c62f000 -     0x7fff8c633fff  libmathCommon.A.dylib (2026.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <FF83AFF7-42B2-306E-90AF-D539C51A4542> /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
    0x7fff8c640000 -     0x7fff8c645ff7  libsystem_network.dylib (??? - ???) <5DE7024E-1D2D-34A2-80F4-08326331A75B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x7fff8cd63000 -     0x7fff8cd65fff  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent (2.0 - 1) <1F31CAFF-C1C6-33D3-94E9-11B721761DDF> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
    0x7fff8ce24000 -     0x7fff8ce32fff  libdispatch.dylib (187.7.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <712AAEAC-AD90-37F7-B71F-293FF8AE8723> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fff8d246000 -     0x7fff8d281fff  libsystem_info.dylib (??? - ???) <35F90252-2AE1-32C5-8D34-782C614D9639> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x7fff8dd8e000 -     0x7fff8dddcfff  libauto.dylib (??? - ???) <D8AC8458-DDD0-3939-8B96-B6CED81613EF> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff8de92000 -     0x7fff8de9dff7  libc++abi.dylib (14.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <8FF3D766-D678-36F6-84AC-423C878E6D14> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff8e1df000 -     0x7fff8e1e3fff  libdyld.dylib (195.5.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <380C3F44-0CA7-3514-8080-46D1C9DF4FCD> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fff8e430000 -     0x7fff8e469fe7  libssl.0.9.8.dylib (44.0.0 - compatibility 0.9.8) <79AAEC98-1258-3DA4-B1C0-4120049D390B> /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
    0x7fff8e5e0000 -     0x7fff8e5e6fff  libmacho.dylib (800.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <165514D7-1BFA-38EF-A151-676DCD21FB64> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fff8e621000 -     0x7fff8e62aff7  libsystem_notify.dylib (80.1.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <A4D651E3-D1C6-3934-AD49-7A104FD14596> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x7fff8ebc8000 -     0x7fff8ebd2ff7  liblaunch.dylib (392.35.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <8F8BB206-CECA-33A5-A105-4A01C3ED5D23> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fff8ebd5000 -     0x7fff8ebf5fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib (1699.24.8 - compatibility 1.0.0) <C56819BB-3779-3726-B610-4CF7B3ABB6F9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff90775000 -     0x7fff90776ff7  libremovefile.dylib (21.1.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <739E6C83-AA52-3C6C-A680-B37FE2888A04> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff907b8000 -     0x7fff907b9fff  libunc.dylib (24.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <337960EE-0A85-3DD0-A760-7134CF4C0AFF> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
    0x7fff90ed0000 -     0x7fff90efbff7  libxslt.1.dylib (3.24.0 - compatibility 3.0.0) <4DB5ED11-004B-36B5-AE5F-2AB714754241> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
    0x7fff91451000 -     0x7fff91553ff7  libxml2.2.dylib (10.3.0 - compatibility 10.0.0) <22F1D1B6-1761-3687-9EFD-036EA15FB2E4> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
    0x7fff9172c000 -     0x7fff91749fff  libxpc.dylib (77.18.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <26C05F31-E809-3B47-AF42-1460971E3AC3> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
    0x7fff9174a000 -     0x7fff9174ffff  libcompiler_rt.dylib (6.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <98ECD5F6-E85C-32A5-98CD-8911230CB66A> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x7fff92568000 -     0x7fff92645fef  libsystem_c.dylib (763.12.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <FF69F06E-0904-3C08-A5EF-536FAFFFDC22> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fff92651000 -     0x7fff92758fe7  libsqlite3.dylib (9.6.0 - compatibility 9.0.0) <EE02BB01-64C9-304D-9719-A35F5CD6D04C> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
    0x7fff92759000 -     0x7fff92759fff  libkeymgr.dylib (23.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <61EFED6A-A407-301E-B454-CD18314F0075> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x7fff92902000 -     0x7fff929f7fff  libiconv.2.dylib (7.0.0 - compatibility 7.0.0) <5C40E880-0706-378F-B864-3C2BD922D926> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
    0x7fff92aed000 -     0x7fff92ceffff  libicucore.A.dylib (46.1.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <38CD6ED3-C8E4-3CCD-89AC-9C3198803101> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff92cf0000 -     0x7fff92cf7fff  libcopyfile.dylib (85.1.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <0AB51EE2-E914-358C-AC19-47BC024BDAE7> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x7fff92f82000 -     0x7fff92ff7ff7  libc++.1.dylib (19.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <C0EFFF1B-0FEB-3F99-BE54-506B35B555A9> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff93155000 -     0x7fff9315afff  libcache.dylib (47.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <1571C3AB-BCB2-38CD-B3B2-C5FC3F927C6A> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x7fff93451000 -     0x7fff93453fff  libquarantine.dylib (36.2.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <48656562-FF20-3B55-9F93-407ACA7341C0> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 66836
    thread_create: 1
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=63.6M resident=27.1M(43%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=36.5M(57%)
Writable regions: Total=150.1M written=47.1M(31%) resident=60.6M(40%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=89.5M(60%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
MALLOC                            124.0M
MALLOC guard page                    48K
MALLOC_LARGE (reserved)            14.5M        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
STACK GUARD                        56.0M
Stack                              11.1M
VM_ALLOCATE                           4K
__DATA                             1216K
__LINKEDIT                         48.9M
__TEXT                             14.7M
shared memory                        12K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             270.5M
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space    256.0M
```

Comment: Why are you installing 1.9.3 into a folder named 1.8.7?

Comment: Bad cut and paste fixed, thanks

Comment: This issue may be restricted to WEBrick. Having trouble getting RubyMine 4.0.2 work with other servers at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is having this problem, migrating to use the much faster `thin` server in development resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to get up and running with your development environment on a newer Lion computer, or do you absolutely need these version numbers to be compatible for some obscure feature? If you just want a modern build that works, I'm using Ruby 1.9.3.p0 and Rails 3.2.1 on Lion, and it's been working for a solid month. I followed Dan Benjamin's old [Hivelogic tutorial](http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-ruby-rubygems-and-rails-on-snow-leopard/) (skipping MySQL the bits and bumping up the version numbers). The only caveat is that you'll need to download Xcode 4 from the App Store.

If you really just need those specific versions to work together then my answer may not be very helpful. Sorry if I've wasted your time.